# Retrieve portion of a Cookie value and store in variable

Tags: php, cookies, string-parsing

I have an ASP.NET Login Application.
When login is successful, my application creates a Cookie.

When created, my cookie resembles something like:

```
Name: LoginCookie

Value: guid=3eb8d82d-bc83-4ab9-b12b-880f84404a1d&login=true
```

My question is, **with PHP, how do I retrieve the 'guid' value and store it in a variable?**

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Why don't you set two separate cookies?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/parse_str)

```
parse_str($_COOKIE['LoginCookie'], $cookie);

// now 'guid' and 'login' are available in the array $cookie:
echo var_export($cookie, 1), PHP_EOL;    

echo $cookie['guid'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give this a shot with regular expressions:

```
$cookieValue = $_COOKIE['LoginCookie'];
preg_match('#guid=([\-a-f0-9]+)#', $cookieValue, $matches);
$guid = $matches[0];
```

If the format of the guid is always like that, the regex could be updated to be more specific.  Right now it will match anything after guid= up until it matches with something that's not a number, a lowercase hex letter (a-f) or a dash.

Using PHP's [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) is also an excellent option if the cookie is in key1=value1&key2=value2... format. It takes URL parameter style strings and breaks it up into multiple key/value pairs.

```
$cookieValue = $_COOKIE['LoginValue'];
parse_str($cookieValue, $cookieParts);
$guid = $cookieParts['guid'];
```

This way is probably a cleaner way of getting these values out the "PHP" way.

Comment: Thank you!! Looks like parse_str is the best way forward.